# Why ratio test for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots \left(2n-1\right)}{2 \cdot 5 \cdot 8 \cdots \left(3n-1\right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots \left(2n-1\right)}{2 \cdot 5 \cdot 8 \cdots \left(3n-1\right)}$$

Apparently the book says ratio test, but I'm unsure why that one is used. I originally thought it could be test for divergence since I'd have $n$'s on top and bottom having a limit of $\frac{2}{3}$ and that would mean the series diverges, but I was wrong.

I can't think of any similar series to justify using ratio test. I suppose I could use process of elimition since I won't use integral test, or root, and then *since I can't think of anything to compare to* then I wouldn't choose direct comparison or limit comparison. Alternating wouldn't work. And so I'm basically left with ratio test.

But is there a better reason to use ratio test in this case? (Preferably a reason that is more direct and "this is why ratio is used here..." (rather than "other tests won't work and so ratio is all you're left with"))

Comment: You use the ratio test because the ratio between successive terms has a simple form: it’s just $(2n-1)/(3n-1)$.  Since this converges to a number less than $1$, the series converges.

Comment: @Milo Brandt I deleted my answer. It's not the first time that I waste my time. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following summation:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^n \dfrac{2k-1}{3k-1}$$

That is not the same as the terms approaching $\dfrac{2}{3}$ as $n \to \infty$. Instead, that product is approaching 0 (since you approach an infinite product of numbers less than one, that product approaches zero).

$$0 \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^n \dfrac{2k-1}{3k-1} \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n = 0$$

So, the infinite product definitely approaches zero. Since the $n+1$-st term contains all of the multipliers of the $n$-th term plus one new one, you can expect the ratio test to cancel everything out, which it does. That is the whole intuition behind using the ratio test. It is not that it is all that is left. It is more that you would expect it to be a simple solution.

Comment: thanks :D I like the intuition about the ratio test being one where things cancel out